# Wrong method called in ATL COM dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, com, atl

I have created a COM dll using ATL.  When I attempt to use it within unmanaged C++ I find that I get a buffer overrun.  I am currently testing using one simple method called OnInitIDA() and all I do within this is a cout statement and return.  When I ran this the HRESULT returned would be 0 however it would not output the line I expected.  By using the step over and step into functions of the debugger I found that rather than entering the code for OnInitIDA when called this actually went into another method called GetInclusionList.  Once I placed a statement within this method and when the app was run this line was printed off.  Does anyone have any idea why the wrong method would be invoked?

If it helps my code has been posted here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3ehFEncKJH7ZDgxMGI1YjgtZTE2MS00ZTBkLWI2NzgtYzVhZjUxOWEzZGI0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question.  Basically, when I created my dll project it inherited from IDispatch, however the interface I was using in the test app expected it to inherit from IUnknown.  This meant the interfaces did not match, with IDispatch inheriting from IUnknown and adding a number of methods.  Change changing these to match the dll worked.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you've changed your interface since building your client.

It would be a good idea to clean and rebuild all your projects.